# Wordpress: Function to add images in text editor

Tags: wordpress, image, function, templates

I'm really new to Wordpress and slowly getting my head around it but I've come across a problem and I don't know how to fix it.

I'm creating pages using the text editor in the backend and I'm pasting html in there.  All's working well and I can output images using this function in functions.php (i found this snippet somwhere but can't remember where)

```
// Create the shortcode
function template_url( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/'. $content .'" alt="" />';
}  

// Add as shortcode
add_shortcode("template", "template_url");
```

and i call it like this

```
[template]images/my-image.jpg[/template]
```

The problem is how do i add some alt text and also add a class to the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `shortcode` with your `custom attributes` like this:-

Add Following code for adding shortcode:

```
function template_url( $atts, $content = null )
{
    extract(
        shortcode_atts( array(
            'alt' => '',
            'width' => '',
            'height' => ''
        ), $atts )
    );

    //And this variable you can use like this:-
    return '<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/'. $content .'" alt="'.$alt.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"/>';
}

add_shortcode("template", "template_url");
```

And use this shortcode in editor:-

```
[template alt="this is alter text" width="400" height="300"]images/my-image.jpg[/template]
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Just what I wanted